# Linker error: undefined symbol _main in module c0.asm

Tags: c, borland

Что может быть не так? Пишу на C.

> linker error: undefined symbol _main
> in module c0.asm

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

void reverse(char s[])

{
int i, j, n;
char temp[MAXLINE];

j = 0;
i = 0;
while (s[j] != '\n') 
++j;
n = j;

for (i = 0; j != 0; ++i) {
temp[j - 1] = s[i];
--j;
}

for (i = 0; n != 0; ++i) {
s[i] = temp[i];
--n;
}
}
```

Comment: @darkrest, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно вы пытаетесь собрать программу без функции main

Comment: а не могли бы подсказать, куда ее  вписать?

Comment: после Вашей функции будет наиболее правильным в Вашем случае.